# Python email: Sending inline images

Tags: python, image, email, smtplib

I wrote a function for sending email to recipients with an *INLINE image* in body, but my image it's send as an attachment.

```
def send_email(recipients):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
    msg['From'] = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    with open('myimage.webp', 'rb') as fp:
        msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
    msgImage.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='myimage.webp')]
    msg.attach(msgImage)
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.login(config.EMAIL_USERNAME, config.EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp_server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_USERNAME, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

function calling:
`send_email(['someone@somewhere.com'])`

Comment: You could create an HTML template. In this template you add your inline image and then it should be sent OK

Comment: Not worked unfortunately  :(

Comment: Typically, emails with embedded images are sent as MHTML. Look it up.

Comment: @ArshiaHaeri-Mehrizi what did you try? Cause I've done it in this way severall times.

Comment: @Linux i sent a MIMEText('<img src="myimage.webp">', 'html') can you send your code to me please?

Comment: I do not have the code with me. But what I said was not to add the image as html in MIMEText, i said to create an html template. Once the template is created you can add it to your python code.

Comment: @zvone can you say some more description?

Comment: @Linux How can i add it?

Comment: @Linux I am a data scientist and beginner in smtp and email sending

Comment: @Linux I created the index.html template, what do I do now?

Comment: I wrote something as a guid for you as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something as a guide for you, here is what I wrote:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

# Sender and receiver
sender= 'mail1o@gmail.com'
receiver= 'mail2@example.com'
passwrd= 'passwd'

# Crear el objeto MIME para el correo
msg= MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = 'Mail subject'

# Create HTML body
body_html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Some text (Title)</h1>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
    <img src="cid:image1">
</body>
</html>
"""

# Add html body to message
msg.attach(MIMEText(body_html, 'html'))

# Conection with server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()

# Loggin
servidor.login(sender, passwrd)

# Send mesg
mail_text = mensaje.as_string()
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, mail_text)

# Close server conection
server.quit()
```

Comment: I'm puzzled why this is an upvoted and accepted answer... One of the key parts of the question was that the MIMEImage is sending as an attachment rather than inline, but this doesn't even attach the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the image as part of the email body (inline) rather than as an attachment, you need to embed the image using HTML within the email's text or HTML body. In the following code, you can use the `MIMEText` class to create the `HTML` portion of the email body. The image is embedded in the `HTML` using an `<img>` tag with the `src` attribute set to `"cid:image1"`, where `"image1"` is the same identifier used in the Content-ID header of the `MIMEImage` attachment. This links the image in the HTML body to the image attachment.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import smtplib
import config  # You should have a config.py file with your email credentials

def send_email(recipients):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
    msg['From'] = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    
    with open('myimage.webp', 'rb') as fp:
        image_data = fp.read()
    
    # add your image source in the img src attribute
    text = """
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>This is an inline image:</p>
            <p><img src="cid:image1"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    
    image = MIMEImage(image_data)
    image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
    msg.attach(image)
    
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.login(config.EMAIL_USERNAME, config.EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp_server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_USERNAME, recipients, msg.as_string())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recipients = ['recipient1@example.com', 'recipient2@example.com']
    send_email(recipients)
```

Comment: After much effort, I was able to send send custom batch emails. I had to add `import ssl` and `context = ssl.create_default_context()` along with the changes to the `with` statement that come with that method, but it worked. Thanks!